# Random number generation and collision check

Tags: random, programming

I was working on a random number generator in NodeJS, I use `Math.random()` which gives a random number *between 0 and 1*. I can get a whole number between `0` and `X` numbers using the following function:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * ( X - 0 + 1) + 1)
```

Now I noticed something. If I want lets say *99 unique numbers* I need to keep my *maximum range of numbers (X) to at least 9999*, i.e double the number of digits. This works where required unique numbers are *999* (3 digits) and when `X` is at least *999999* (6 digits), and so on.

I don't know why, but this gives me least amount of collisions. Is there a mathematical reason behind this or something? Like is there a rule which says something similar?

Regards

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write << If I want lets say *99 unique numbers* I need to keep my *maximum range of numbers (X)* to ***at least 9999*** >>?

Comment: @rtybase actually no... well kinda yes. I didn't think about it that way. Yeah. At least 9999. I have updated it to atleast. Thanks!

Comment: @echo_salik ok ... one more question, have you tried to calculate the [collision probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492584/whats-the-probability-of-generating-an-existing-account-id/3492618#3492618) given the number of samples $99$ and the "space" size of $9999$?

Comment: @rtybase umm... no... i have not. I'll try it out. Is there a calculator out there which woul do something like this?

Comment: Compare these 3 values for the sample size $99$: [with "space" size $99999$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-99999%21%2F%28%2899999-99%29%21+*+99999%5E99%29) vs [with "space" size $9999$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-9999%21%2F%28%289999-99%29%21+*+9999%5E99%29) vs [with "space" size $999$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-999%21%2F%28%28999-99%29%21+*+999%5E99%29) ... larger the "space" the better.

Comment: so smaller the result better the collision avoidance?

Comment: The result is the probability of having at least one collision, so yes - smaller the better.

Comment: I am getting an error for the numbers I am using, I guess they are too big.

Comment: Most likely they are too big. You exercise now is to prove (mathematically) that doubling the digits of "space" size makes the collision probability $P(k,n)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ where $n$-"space" size, $k$ - sample size. Knowing that $$P(k,n)=1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}$$
For example $P(99,9999)=0.385379...$

Comment: oooohhhh i get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Further to the comments**, let's try to find some bounds for the probability of having at least one collision
$$P(k,n)=1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k} \tag{1}$$
where $k$ is the sample size and $n$ is the "space" size, $k<n$. For more details see [Birthday Paradox wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492584/whats-the-probability-of-generating-an-existing-account-id/).

---

> **Proposition 1**. We have
>   $$1-e^{-\frac{(k-1)k}{2n}}\leq P(k,n)\leq 1-e^{k-1-n\log{\frac{n-1}{n-k}}} \tag{2}$$

First of all
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)...\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right) \tag{2a}$$
Now, [using](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1) 
$$e^{-\frac{x}{1-x}}\leq 1-x \leq e^{-x}, x\in[0,1)$$
and indeed each $\frac{i}{n}\in[0,1)$, for $i=1..k-1$, we have from $(2a)$
$$e^{-\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{2}{n-2}-...-\frac{k-1}{n-(k-1)}}\leq 
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}\leq
e^{-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n}-...-\frac{k-1}{n}}\iff\\
e^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{n-j-n}{n-j}}\leq 
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}\leq 
e^{-\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}i\right)}\iff$$
$$e^{k-1-n\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n-j}\right)}\leq 
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}\leq 
e^{-\frac{(k-1)k}{2n}} \tag{2b}$$
Using [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) as a technique, it's easy to show
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n-j}\leq\int\limits_{n-k}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\log{\frac{n-1}{n-k}}$$
Multiply by $-n$, add $k-1$, apply this to $(2b)$ and we have
$$e^{k-1-n\log{\frac{n-1}{n-k}}}\leq 
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}\leq 
e^{-\frac{(k-1)k}{2n}} $$
Multiply by $-1$, add $1$ and we have $(2)$.

---

**A few observations**. We have 
$$k=\underbrace{99..9}_{t \text{ times}}=10^t -1$$
and
$$n=\underbrace{99..9}_{2t \text{ times}}=10^{2t} -1=\left(10^t -1\right)\left(10^t +1\right)=k(k+2) \tag{3}$$

---

Now let's plug $(3)$ into $(2)$ ant take the limit when $k\to\infty$.
$$1-e^{-\frac{(k-1)k}{2n}}=
1-e^{-\frac{(k-1)k}{2k(k+2)}}=
1-e^{-\frac{k-1}{2(k+2)}}\to 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}},
k\to\infty \tag{4a}$$
For the other side (to make it simple), I will use [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) and the fact that $e^x$ is continuous:
$$k-1-n\log{\frac{n-1}{n-k}}=
k-1-k(k+2)\log{\frac{k^2+2k-1}{k^2+k}}=\\
k-1-k(k+2)\log{\left(1+\frac{k-1}{k^2+k}\right)}=\\
k-1-k(k+2)\left(\frac{k-1}{k^2+k}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{k-1}{k^2+k}\right)^2+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)=\\
k-1\left(1-\frac{k(k+2)}{k^2+k}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{k(k+2)(k-1)^2}{(k^2+k)^2}-O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\\
-\frac{k(k-1)}{k^2+k}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{k(k+2)(k-1)^2}{(k^2+k)^2}-O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)
\to -1 + \frac{1}{2} = \\
-\frac{1}{2}, k\to\infty$$
As a result
$$1-e^{k-1-n\log{\frac{n-1}{n-k}}} \to 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}},
k\to\infty \tag{4b}$$

---

From $(2)$, $(4a)$, $(4b)$ and [squeezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

> Given $(3)$ or $n=k(k+2)$ we have:
>   $$P(k,n) \to 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}, k\to\infty \tag{5}$$

Which is less than $0.4$, so there is "less than half" chance to obtain a collision.